# Is it a good practice to allow android users to access my database?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am using my own computer as database server and for a simple example; i want to save users registeration informations and check these informations while a user logging in. I am using apache,php and mysql. In order to check users informations I allowed all ip addresses to access my database server. I think this is obviously wrong. What is the true way to accomplish my goal? Which tools should I use?

Comment: Since you've said you are using php my guess is that you are writing REST service in it and if you are in my opinion only it should have access to database server, while the rest of android apps should access data through REST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a little more complicated than allowing everyone to the database server, the problem is not exactly that you are allowing all ip addresses to access the server but what everyone is able to do is the real problem.

Apache, PHP and MySQL is very popular for setting up a database server but it is certainly not the easiest and most secure method if you don't have previous experience setting up this kind of servers

There is alternatives such as Node and Mongo DB which makes the Database Server setup a-lot easier and the documentation is much simpler than using PHP, Apache and MySQL

This is definitely up to you

If you want to continue setting up your server on this enviroment there is a few things you have to consider

> - Encryption
> - Brute force attacks
> - URL manipulation
> - some other PHP    security gaps

You probably want a good encryption for your database using AES from 128 to 256 bits is one alternative

Brute force attacks is when someone want to access your database trying alot of passwords per second, you can prevent this kind of things using PHP

URL maniplulation is tricky since you have to setup "permissions" for each new route you create for example *www.mywebsite.com/admin/importantstuff.php* should only be accessed when someone is logged in as admin and similar scenarios

There is alot of this covered on this Guide if you follow step by step you should have a pretty solid server up and running

Or you can also see some documenation for MongoDB and you can have a server up and running in an hour or so with most of the security already taken care of, just don't forget to change the root password!

[Create a secure login PHP, MySQL](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

[Prevent PHP and SQL vulnerabilities](https://php.earth/docs/security/intro)

[MongoDB Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/)

[Avoid malicious attacks MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/update-how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data)

Hope it helps.